# How to create SSAS dimensions from an Entity with self-referencing association?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, olap-cube

I'm working on a SQL Server Analysis Services project to build a multidimentional OLAP cube.
I would like to create a tree of dimensions (parent/child) from a SQL Entity intitled "Category" with self-referencing association. The AdventureWorks project from Microsoft works with two entities (Category and a child Subcategory).

I created my categories and I want to create my dimensions (parent/child) like that :

```
Category A
  Category A.1
    Category A.1.1
    Category A.1.2
  Category A.2
Category B
  Category B.1
  Category B.2
```

Any idea to do that ?
The concept is to be able to browse data by using categories as dimensions.

Thanks !

Comment: Does this help? http://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/parent-child-dimension/
Basically, you create the parent-child relationship in the DSV, then create the dimension and hierarchy, then set the relevant properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the suggested article, the simplest way is to create a new dimension by selecting parent_id field, then changing the behavior of the field in SSDT (dimension panel) to "Parent". All works well and you can browse a tree.
Moreover, when you select a parent node it will include all children.